# Add triangle at bottom-middle in uiimageview like marker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to add a triangle in bottom-middle position on my uiimageview but I don't know how to do that this is my code

```
let img_view: UIImageView!
img_view = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
let url_img = URL(string: Constants.img_url+"\(img)")!
img_view.af_setImage(withURL: url_img)
img_view.layer.cornerRadius = img_view.frame.size.height/2
img_view.layer.borderWidth = 1
img_view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 229, green: 57, blue: 53, alpha: 1).cgColor
img_view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I wanna do that like this image1 but I have only a circle like image2

image 1
[image]

image 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You got perfect output for your code. You can achieve this small down arrow by adding another `ImageView` just below the existing one. This is one of the way of achieving this UI. To add another image view,

```
let downArrowImageView: UIImageView!
downArrowImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: img_view.frame.width / 2, y: img_view.frame.height, width: 10, height: 10))

downArrowImageView.image = "Down arrow image"
```

Then add this `downArrowImageView` to corresponding view.

Thanks.

Comment: is it posible to add the  arrow as uiview?

Comment: Yes you can, but if  you go with UIView you need to write rotating logic to get arrow like look.